# Determine the smallest prime which does not divide any five digit number...

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Determine the smallest prime number which does not divide any five digit number and whose digits are in strictly increasing order.

I have no idea how to solve this contest problem. Please help.

Comment: Is this from an active contest?  If so, solutions should wait until the contest is over.

Comment: I would start with checking if $56789$ is prime, and then continue to $6$-digit numbers. The first one to check is $123457$, which turns out to be prime.

Comment: No this is not from an active contest

Comment: Wait,  the prime has increasing digits, or the 5-digit number has increasing digits?  If it's the prime then ... well, barak manos's comment and solution.  If it's the 5 digit number  (as I first interpreted it) that has increasing digits.  Then I'm stumped.

Comment: @fleablood: The word "and" before "whose" implies that it refers to the prime, not to the five-digit number.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that when I reread it.  But on first reading I thought it was the other way.  For a cute puzzle (much easier than it looks) Try to find the smallest prime that does not divide any 5 digit number with increasing digits.  For a cuter and even easier puzzle find the smallest prime that doesn't divide a six digit number with increasing digits.

Comment: And apparently I'm not the only one who misinterpreted this:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1350967/find-the-smallest-prime-number-that-doesnt-divide-any-5-digit-number-whose-digi

Answer (score 2):

Any prime smaller than $50000$ would obviously divide some $5$-digit number.

So the first number to check is $56789$, which is not prime, as $56789=109\cdot521$.

The second number to check is $123456$, which is even, hence obviously not prime.

The third number to check is $123457$, which is prime.

Comment: To shorten an already very efficient proof:  the OP didn't say that $p$ had to be a proper divisor of a five digit number, so any five digit prime would be excluded because it divides itself.

Comment: @lulu: Hahaha, that's right. So OP should simply check $6$-digit numbers with their digits in strictly increasing order. That makes the first two statements in my answer redundant. Thanks.

Comment: Slick! but... "before I go grubbing in the dirt I want to make sure there's a potato in there".  If this is trial and error is there any assurance that trial and error would be efficient?  Going through numbers one by one is never an efficient strategy.  But ... nice answer.

Comment: @fleablood: In general I agree, but in this specific case... Well - it's $3$ numbers in total. The first one is redundant as implied in the comment above by lulu, and the second one requires $O(0)$ computational effort.

Answer (score 1):

Divisors of $5$-digit numbers are smaller than their square roots, so your prime has to be larger than $\sqrt{10^6} = 1000$. Start looking by increasing digits, i.e. check $1237$, $1239$, $1347$, ... for primeness. It just so happens that $1237$ is in fact a prime.

Comment: Half the divisors of a number are smaller than its square root. The other half is larger. $1237$ divides $12370$, a $5$ digit number.

Comment: $49999$ divides $99998$, but $49999>\sqrt{99998}$.

Comment: Why should the prime non divisors be have increasing digits?